# Logo Over The Text HTML

Tags: html, css

I have one question, I'm building one html file with text and I've added one logo for every page when PRINTING, but have one issue. My issue is logo is displayed over the text; see: https://prnt.sc/ll6ujn

How to make this texted display after logo? Please help me. Thanks

My code is :

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: Set margins at printer options

Comment: but if your elements are positioned, then have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: Can you paste a copy of your HTML & CSS?

Comment: Hello, my code is; https://jsfiddle.net/linuxman/94azxuhw/  @AlexMulchinock

Comment: @linuxman1 - I'd suggest adding the code to your question, under 'My code is :'

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent the image, try setting various attributes on the image and text. For example, you can try one of the following for text and images:

```
p {display: none;}
p {display: inline;}
p {display: block;}
p {display: inline-block;}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello @CodeRocks im tried this but again display logo over the text; my code is; jsfiddle.net/linuxman/94azxuhw